# How can i change session when open url in another tab in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I am developing one web application in asp.net. I am opening my all pages on pop up window. I want to expire my session or change the session value when someone copy the url and paste it into another tab. How can i implement it ? 
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using this

```
   string referer = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer))
        {
            Response.Redirect("../Index.htm");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to check [Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx). The Referrer would be empty if the user copy pastes a URL.

A couple of points you should consider before using this:

1. Provide exceptions for any pages that can be directly entered by
   the user. For e.g. the login page or a page that can be bookmarked
2. I believe a pop can be opened from Javascript, without a referrer. Make sure your existing code is not using this method to open a pop up.

For a generic way to determine if the user has opened a new tab, see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MultipleTabWindows.aspx)